# Elliptic curve points addition is not associative

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory

I've found [an article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Standard_Projective_Coordinates) that says how to add points in projective coordinates.But in my implementation these points don't form a group.
Fields:

```
private final BigInteger x;

private final BigInteger y;

private final BigInteger z;

private final BigInteger a;

private final BigInteger b;

private final BigInteger n;
```

Constructor:

```
private EllipticCurveProjective(BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger z, BigInteger a, BigInteger b,
        BigInteger n) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.n = n;
}
```

Random curve and point generator:

```
public static EllipticCurveProjective generateRandomCurve(BigInteger n) {
        BigInteger x = BigInteger.probablePrime(n.bitLength(), new 

    Random()).mod(n);
            BigInteger y = BigInteger.probablePrime(n.bitLength()-1, new Random()).mod(n);
            BigInteger a = BigInteger.probablePrime(n.bitLength()-1, new Random()).mod(n);
            //This b should fit Weierstrass equation y^2=x^3+ax+b, where b=y^2-x^3-ax
            BigInteger b = (y.modPow(TWO, n).subtract(x.modPow(THREE, n)).subtract(a.multiply(x))).mod(n);
            return new EllipticCurveProjective(x, y, BigInteger.ONE, a, b, n);
        }
```

Doubling and addition:

```
public EllipticCurveProjective doublePoint() {
        /*
         *  if (Y == 0) 
            return POINT_AT_INFINITY
         */
        if (y.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return getInfinityPoint();
        }
        //W = a*Z^2 + 3*X^2
        BigInteger w = a.multiply(z.modPow(TWO, n)).add(THREE.multiply(x.modPow(TWO, n)));
        //S = Y*Z
        BigInteger s = y.multiply(z).mod(n);
        //B = X*Y*S
        BigInteger b = x.multiply(y).mod(n).multiply(s).mod(n);
        //H = W^2 - 8*B
        BigInteger h = w.modPow(TWO, n).subtract(EIGHT.multiply(b)).mod(n);
        //X' = 2*H*S
        BigInteger x3 = TWO.multiply(h).mod(n).multiply(s).mod(n);
        //Y' = W*(4*B - H) - 8*Y^2*S^2
        BigInteger y3 = w.multiply(FOUR.multiply(b).subtract(h).mod(n)).mod(n)
                .subtract(EIGHT.multiply(y.modPow(TWO, n)).multiply(s.modPow(TWO, n)).mod(n)).mod(n);
        //Z' = 8*S^3
        BigInteger z3 = EIGHT.multiply(s.modPow(THREE, n)).mod(n);
        return new EllipticCurveProjective(x3, y3, z3, a, this.b, n);
    }

    public EllipticCurveProjective addPoint(EllipticCurveProjective ec) {
        if (ec.equals(this)) {
            return this.doublePoint();
        }
        //U1 = Y2*Z1
        BigInteger u1 = ec.getY().multiply(z).mod(n);
        //U2 = Y1*Z2
        BigInteger u2 = y.multiply(ec.getZ()).mod(n);
        //V1 = X2*Z1
        BigInteger v1 = ec.getX().multiply(z).mod(n);
        //V2 = X1*Z2
        BigInteger v2 = x.multiply(ec.getZ()).mod(n);
        // if (V1 == V2)
        if (v1.equals(v2)) {
            //if (U1 != U2)
            if (!u1.equals(u2)) {
                return getInfinityPoint();
            } else {
                // return POINT_DOUBLE(X1, Y1, Z1)
                return this.doublePoint();
            }
        }
        //U = U1 - U2
        BigInteger u = u1.subtract(u2).mod(n);
        //V = V1 - V2
        BigInteger v = v1.subtract(v2).mod(n);
        //W = Z1*Z2
        BigInteger w = z.multiply(ec.getZ()).mod(n);
        //A = U^2*W - V^3 - 2*V^2*V2
        BigInteger A = u.modPow(TWO, n).multiply(w).mod(n).subtract(v.modPow(THREE, n)).mod(n)
                .subtract(TWO.multiply(v.modPow(TWO, n)).multiply(v2)).mod(n);
        //X3 = V*A
        BigInteger x3 = v.multiply(A).mod(n);
        //U*(V^2*V2 - A) - V^3*U2
        BigInteger y3 = u.multiply(v.modPow(TWO, n).multiply(v2).mod(n).subtract(A))
                .subtract(v.modPow(THREE, n).multiply(u2)).mod(n);
        //Z3 = V^3*W
        BigInteger z3 = v.modPow(THREE, n).multiply(w).mod(n);
        return new EllipticCurveProjective(x3, y3, z3, a, b, n);
    }
```

But if I do this:

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.probablePrime(32, new Random());
        EllipticCurveProjective point = EllipticCurveProjective.generateRandomCurve(n);
        //p+p+p
        EllipticCurveProjective result1 = point.addPoint(point).addPoint(point);
        //p+(p+p)
        EllipticCurveProjective result2 = point.addPoint(point.addPoint(point));
        System.out.println(result1.equals(result2));
```

It will return false, meaning that `p+p+p` is not `p+(p+p)`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is more like a programming question... By the way how did you define equals ? Also your code is kinda hard to read. You should also provide a .java file (gist) so we could fiddle with it. While we get how you do this, if you provide also us the file, it will be easier for us to help you. :/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the implementation of `is_equals` (which you don't show) is likely to be the problem.

In projective coordinates, a triple $(x,y,z)$ corresponds to a solution $u=xz^{-1}, v=yz^{-1}$ to the equation $v^2 = u^3 + au + b$.  Hence, two triples $(x,y,z), (x',y',z')$ with $xz^{-1} = x'z'^{-1}$ and $yz^{-1} = y'z'^{-1}$ are the same, because they both correspond to the same solution (also known as point).  Two such triples are two different *representations* of the same point (in effect, different ways of spelling it); just like in Scientific Notation, $3 \times 10^2$ and $0.3 \times 10^3$ are really the same number.

With your addition routine, the addition $(A+B)+C$ will be the same point as $A+(B+C)$ but not necessarily the same representation of that point.  Unless your `is_equals` function accounts for it, it would appear to break associativity.